# Why are nonces working in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: nonce

I created the nonce when I localize a script file:

```
wp_localize_script('cad-search', 'cad_ajax', 
    array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
         'nonce'=> wp_create_nonce('cad_nonce'))
); 

wp_enqueue_script('cad-search');
```

But when the nonce is evaluated in the function called through AJAX the values are not the same:

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'cad_nonce')) {
    exit('Missing nonce! Please refresh the page.');
}
```

This code works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Does Chrome cache the page?

Comment: That could be a possibility since it is only happening on the front end. If so, what can be done about it? Caching would make nonces impossible to use.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off a cache plugin, Fast Cache in this case, and adding 'define('WP_CACHE', false);' to the wp-config.php file seems to have resolved this issue.